# Sending message from server to client without managing sockets

Tags: iphone, http, connection, client-server

Im building a chat app for iPhone and im using NSURLConnection with HTTP Post and Get to send messages from client to server. From what i understand this is a non-persist connection, because NSURLConnection open and close connection for each HTTP request, am i right??
In my server i just response to this messages.

My main problem is how to send a message from client A to client B? 
client A sends the message to the server with HTTP POST, but how can i send the message from the server to client B if im not keeping a persists connection to client B?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [push notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) to inform the client that it has an unread message.

Comment: hey, I dont think push notification designed for that purpose, and its not reliable..